# access path helper for an engine when testing parent Rails app with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have a Rails engine and a Rails 4 app that contains it. I want to write an RSpec test in the parent Rails app that verifies one of the Rails app's controllers redirects to a path inside the engine. When I run `rake routes` for my Rails app, I see the engine path I want, and it's named. I can refer to that path inside a view in my Rails app by saying `my_engine.my_engine_path`. However, `my_engine` doesn't seem to be a thing inside my Rails app's RSpec controller test. I don't want to do the following in my app's `spec_helper.rb` because that seems to clobber my app's routes with my engine's:

```
config.include Module.new {
  def self.included base
    base.routes { MyEngine::Engine.routes }
  end
}, type: :controller
```

When I do the following, I get `undefined local variable or method 'my_engine'`:

```
expect(response).to redirect_to(my_engine.my_engine_path(some_route_param))
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in my routes. I was using a `path` parameter instead of `id` because the controller deals with files on the file system, not database records. I had `resources :my_controller` instead of `resources :my_controller, param: :path, constraints: {path: /.*/}`. So doing `expect(response).to redirect_to(my_engine_path(some_route_param))` works fine in my app's RSpec controller test, no `my_engine.` prefix necessary.